# Check for two decimal digit number in string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I have two sets of records

Set 1:

```
-11
-12
-12 AN    
''    
-134
-125
+135
```

Set 2:

```
1.15
1.1
```

In Set 1 I need to check which values are either blank `''` or start with a `+` sign and are greater than 125.

In Set 2 I need to check which values have less than two decimal places

Example output for the above sets:

```
''
+135
1.1
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @akhrot check my answer, It should work for you.

Comment: @akhrot, set2 is set of varchars or decimals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL-Server could be something like that:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT Col
FROM set1
WHERE Col = '' OR Col LIKE'+%' AND (CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(Col,'+',''),'-','') AS INT) > 125)
)
SELECT * FROM cte
UNION ALL
SELECT Col
FROM set2
WHERE Col LIKE '%._'
```

OUTPUT:

```
''  -- blank
+135
1.1
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/174b8/6)**

Comment: Integer numbers also have less than two decimal places and also, what about negative numbers?

Comment: Integer numbers don't have dot and for negative numbers added 1 more replace.

Comment: @akhrot . . . You can accept whichever answer you like.  However, you should be aware that SQL Server does *not* guarantee the order of evaluation of the `AND` operator so you can still get a conversion error on `'-12 AN'`.  In addition, this code does generate an error on `'+12 AN'` (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/443), although that is not one of your sample data values.  The `case` statement is the *only* way in SQL Server to control the order of expression evaluation in a single statement.

Answer (score 2):

For the first set, you can use the `like` operator to check if a string starts with '+' and then cast it to `numeric` and compare it with `125`. Using `isnumeric` beforehand will help avoid casting errors:

```
WHERE col = '' OR
      (col LIKE '+%' AND ISNUMERIC(col) AND CAST(col AS NUMERIC) > 125)
```

For the second set, you can use the `like` operator with `_`, the single character wildcard:

```
WHERE col NOT LIKE '%.__%'
```

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
where f = '' or (f like '+%' and isnumeric(f) = 1 and f > 0)

where isnumeric(f) = 1 and f like '%.[0-9]'
```

Answer (score 2):

**First:**

```
WHERE v = '' OR (v NOT LIKE '%[^+0-9]%' AND v > 125)
```

**Second:**

```
WHERE v NOT LIKE '%[^.0-9]%' AND (v LIKE '%._' OR (v NOT LIKE '%.%' AND v LIKE '%_%'))
```

For decimals:

```
WHERE FLOOR(v*10) = v*10
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values are `nvarchar`, here it is:

```
SELECT
    Value
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    Value = '' -- is empty string
    OR
        Value LIKE '+%' -- starts with a plus sign
        AND ISNUMERIC(Value) = 1 -- is a number
        AND CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,10), Value) > 125 -- is greater than 125

UNION ALL

SELECT
    Value
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    ISNUMERIC(Value) = 1 -- is a number
    AND (CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,10), Value) * 10) % 1 = 0 -- has at most 2 decimal places
```

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your table structure i have split this into two queries

```
SELECT set1
FROM yourtable
WHERE set1 IS NULL
OR set1 = ''''
OR (LEFT(set1 , 1) = '+' AND set > 125
```

This returns null and '' values as well as values starting with '+' and greater than 125

```
SELECT set2
FROM yourtable
WHERE LENGTH(SUBSTRING(set2,CHARINDEX(".",set2))) < 2
```

This returns all values that have less than 2 decimal places

Comment: Hi Matt, i am getting error message as  'INSTR' is not a recognized built-in function name. Please help

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky, because you don't want to get a conversion error.  The following should manage this:

```
select *
from set1
where 1 = (case when col = '' then 1
                when col like '+[0-9][0-9[0-9]%' and isnumeric(col, left(5))
                     (case when cast(left(col, 5)) > 125 then 1 end)
                when col like '+[0-9][0-9[0-9]%' and isnumeric(col, left(4))
                     (case when cast(left(col, 4)) > 125 then 1 end)
           end)
```

The second is easier:

```
select *
from set2
where col like '%[.][0-9][0-9]%
```

Conversions of strings to numbers -- without an error -- is troublesome in SQL Server.  In almost all cases, you have no idea the ordering of the operations.  So, the following often generates an error:

```
select s.*, cast(col as number)
from set1
where isnumeric(col);
```

because the `cast()` can be processed *before* the `isnumeric()`.  The *only* statement that controls the order of processing is `case`, which is why the first version liberally uses `case` in the `where` clause.  Note:  subqueries and CTEs do not affect the ordering.

SQL Server 2012+ offers the `try_convert()` function, which facilitates error processing in conversions.